# Weird issue with Authorize.net payment module

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, authorize.net

In our front end, the customer is able to select their shipping option (matrix rate, all works great) everything goes through and adds up properly. Customer checks out successfully with their credit card via Authorize.net. Smooth as silk.

BUT

On our Authorize.net transaction receipt, the processed amount is the product net value only, EXCLUDING shipping & tax amounts. Huge problem!

Toward the bottom of the tx receipt (under “Additional Information") tax and freight are listed. The values are shown there, but the settlement report only reflects the net cost of the product. We asked the Authorize.net rep about this and she said those fields are only informational, and the shopping cart needs to add the freight to the charge. Otherwise, those values won’t get charged to the customer.

I am desperately looking for a solution here. Has anyone had the same issue and solved it? Does anyone have any tips for us?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you asked a question of WebShopApps regarding this issue with Matrix Rate? Also, you should set the debug flag to true in the Auth.net config in System > Config > Payment Methods

Comment: @benmarks Yes i have enabled the debug flag and its showing the shipping charges are applying but not getting charged.Also i have checked with test authorize.net account where its charging the shipping correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an issue with Matrixrates, its higher up the chain. It sounds like a checkout issue, are you using a custom checkout?

I'd suggest test with tablerates or live rates to see how that performs, just to eliminate completely the shipping side of the equation. Then look at any extensions that are overriding/changing the totalling (Matrixrates is not one of these)